# Stored procedure error with linked server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, oledb, linked-server

I have set up a stored procedure to update a database on my linked server

```
CREATE procedure MyProcedure
@myfield varchar(50),
@mycolumn varchar(10)

AS

UPDATE MyDB
SET myfield = @myfield
WHERE mycolumn = @mycolumn
GO
```

And then executing it like this

```
exec linkedDB...MyProcedure @myfield = '0', @mycolumn = '12345'
```

But I keep getting this error

> Could not set up parameter for remote server 'linkedDB'

I've done a search on the web for it but it doesn't seem to come up with anything

**UPDATE**

Here's what i'm trying now

```
EXEC ('MyProcedure (?,?)', '0', '12345') AT [linkedDB]
```

Seems to be giving me this error now

> Incorrect syntax near ','

I'm using OLE DB with SQL Server 2000

**UPDATE**

Also tried this

```
exec linkedDB...MyProcedure '0', '12345'
```

And I now get this error

> Syntax error or access violation "parse error near ';'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow paramaters i think you have to activate the **Dynamic Parameter** option in your [linked server provider properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188095.aspx):
You can find them in Sql Server managament studio, under Server Objects/ Linked Servers/ Providers/ Right click Properties on the desired providers

> **Dynamic parameter**
>
> Indicates that the provider allows '?' parameter marker syntax for
>   parameterized queries. Set this option
>   only if the provider supports the
>   ICommandWithParameters interface and
>   supports a '?' as the parameter
>   marker. Setting this option allows SQL
>   Server to execute parameterized
>   queries against the provider. The
>   ability to execute parameterized
>   queries against the provider can
>   result in better performance for
>   certain queries.

**EDIT From Comment:**

For OLEDB the parameter marker is *?* (question mark) without any name.
Youshould try to call the stored procedure with this kind of sintax:

```
EXEC ('exec MyProcedure ?, ?', @parVal1, @parVal2) AT [LINKED SERVER]
```

Comment: I've just changed the setting on the linked server but it doesn't seem to have changed anything? any ideas?

Comment: do the linked server provider allow parameters?

Comment: i'm not sure how to check, what kind of DB is your linked server?

Comment: It's an OLE DB running SQL server 2000

Comment: i have some difficult to test it, however, i edited the EXEC. Try that without parenthesis

Comment: Ok, i was finally able to test it! The last exec i made works fine for me!

Comment: I still seem to be getting the `Incorrect syntax near ','` error?

Comment: i have a doubt, the Sql Server 2000 is your db or the linked db?

Comment: the linked db is sql server 2000

Comment: could copy/paste here the command that is giving you the error now?

Comment: I tried this `EXEC ('exec MyProcedure ?, ?', '0', '12345') AT [linkedDB]` and it gave me the error - i'm quite new to all this so appreciate you bearing with me :)

Comment: mmm it looks fine to me :\ Is your DB an SQL 2005 or 2008?

Comment: I thought it was 200 but it may be 2005 definitely not 2008 - is it different for 2005?

Comment: I'm no t talking about the linked server, but the server you are connecting from. Because the exec command is different in 2000 and 2005/2008.